Identify a European movie where father and son are cutting each other's hair with a mechanical clipper
I remember one key scene:
Supposedly, father and son are cutting each other's hair under a tree with a mechanical haircutter (like this one) in front of a small hut.
I also remember ...

The weather is mostly sunny and warm
Not many dialogs, focus on ambient sounds (maybe this is my perception)
High-key, probably low saturation
Plays 1970 ~ 1980
Plays in southern Europe (Spain, France, Italy, ...)
Movie release date unknown, probably pre 1990 since ...
I watched it mid-90s
The genre is probably drama or love movie
The movie was not animated
It was a Spanish, French or Italian production
A hut and probably also a mansion with a pool
Scenes on the country side and city (not 100% sure)
It could be that a (the) young man is an artist (painter, photographer, ...) (not 100% sure)
A scene where the younger man drives in a car with one (or more) woman between a city and the countryside (not 100% sure)


can you tell us when and how you saw it, was this animated or not, was it American, British, or another country?  please read our passage on id questions here:  http://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic
